# Looking to replicate this dial in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Looking to replicate this dial (see link below) in illustrator, can someone point me in the direction of a tutorial or give me some ideas on how to do this? Many thanks!

It's really just the orange segmented circle that I'm interested in.

[image]

Comment: There should be tutorials about these things. Probably too long to answer here.

Comment: I've been looking for a tutorial and can't find one.

Comment: Hopefullly somebody finds time to write one here, because that's what you're asking. There is no short answer for this.

Comment: Try googling something along the lines of 'Illustrator tutorial volume dial', there will be some relevant knowledge in the 1.5 million results ;)

Comment: The please add that information to your question with an [edit]. You can click that link right there in this comment or the one under your post. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a transform effect (*Effect → Distort & Transform → Transform...*) on a single rectangle to create the bars. Set a stroke on the rectangle for the spacing (you can uncheck "Scale Strokes & Effects" to keep the strokes at the same size then...

[image]

Expand the result (*Object → Expand Appearance*). Then drag it to the brushes panel and select "Art Brush" from the new brush dialog...

You can then use your brush on an ellipse (and delete a segment thereof)...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a dashed stroke... unfortunately Illustrator only lets you set a limited number of distinct dashes through the GUI, you can write it manually with an SVG though.

This for example...

(The important part of which being [`stroke-dasharray`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/stroke-dasharray) which is just a comma separated list of dash and gap lengths.)

```
<svg width="600px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 600 600">
<circle cx="300" cy="300" r="257.586"
        fill="none" stroke="#F7931E" stroke-width="50"
        stroke-dasharray="40,10,60,10,80,10,100,10,120,10,140,10,160,10,180,10,200,10,220,100000" />
</svg>
```

Gives us this...

[image]